# Verified Solana Programs

Tags: anchor, solana-program, verify

I remembered we used to have [Anchor Registry](https://www.apr.dev/) that allowed users to view the source code for programs on Solana.

Sadly, it looks like the site isn't working or isn't being maintained anymore.

Does anyone have any idea if there is an alternative? IMO having verified code + ability to read / write via block explorers (like etherscan) goes a long ways to increasing trust, transparency and traceability on Solana.

Right now, interacting with programs is like a black box and almost we have to trust that the program isn't doing anything nefarious.

Verify, don't trust should be the motto.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a great list: https://twitter.com/StrategicHash/status/1723434711698034739

Playground recently added a list of open source program (not complete, but a great mix): https://beta.solpg.io/programs

This blog from OtterSec may be of interest to you: https://osec.io/blog/2022-08-27-reverse-engineering-solana

Some programs also publish their IDLs on chain, which is accessible via Solana Explorer (if published).

Comment: Do you have an example of a program that published their IDL on chain, how is this done, what does it look like?

Comment: Here's an example of Marinade Finance staking program: https://explorer.solana.com/address/MarBmsSgKXdrN1egZf5sqe1TMai9K1rChYNDJgjq7aD/anchor-program

If you are using anchor, you can publish the IDL by using `anchor idl` [command](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/cli#idl).